# How do I add a new swift file into the SCM? (Xcode 11.4)

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11.4

I noticed that my newly created swift file in the xcode project was faded, and had the letter 'A' beside it unlike my other existing swift files that had the letter 'M' beside it. I found out that A means that it is a new file and should be added to SCM. I never had this issue before while creating a new file, so what and how exactly am I supposed to add the new file to the SCM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have checked [image: Create Git repository] checkbox while creating a new project.

Now your project is tracking all additions / modifications since it was created. If you are not interested in seeing what has changed, you can ignore this.

In case you want to see what has changed since the initial commit - you can use any Git client like https://gitup.co/

Comment: I think what xcode shows while creating a new file is different in the xcode version I am using (11.4.1), there is no option that you've shown in the answer. I tried searching for it in the source control, but I couldn't really find it.

Comment: It is visible **while creating a new project** and NOT while creating new files.

Comment: Oh, sorry! I just found that option and it is indeed checked while making a new project. Is there a way I can change that in an already existing project?

Comment: You can use `Terminal.app` to delete git setup for your project `cd /Users/user/Desktop/Test && rm -rf .git`. If that doesn't help, you can simply copy all folders/project file of your project and paste it in a new folder somewhere else. Opening the copied project from new folder won't show this issue.